# Optimal way to identify item in array that occurs at specific time

Tags: c#, arrays, midi

I need to preface this by saying I have no formal training, so even though 18 months later I'm handling about 100,000 lines of C# code across three major programs, it's all been through trial and error (and StackOverflow). I've found that over the past few months I've been able to revisit and improve my code substantially. Hopefully one of you with more training can offer a better solution to my current problem and it not have to wait months before I catch up on my own.

My current project is a program to play the audio to a song along with a carefully crafted MIDI file that represents the audio. The program reads a MIDI file for specific tracks and notes within those tracks. I use NAudio to do so. The value of each note I care about is stored in a List of the MIDINote class I created for this:

```
public class MIDINote
{
public int NoteNumber { get; set; }
public double NoteStart { get; set; }
public double NoteLength { get; set; }
public bool Played { get; set; }
}
```

The NoteStart and NoteLength are in seconds (the conversion from absolute time works beautifully to 5 decimal places, no need to worry).

Now here's the part I'm hoping you can show me how to do better.

I have a timer that among many other things increases the value of a counter.
After increasing that value, I want to know exactly which notes, if any, are "on" at that point (i.e. either start exactly then, or have already started but still haven't passed). Then I do a variety of things with the notes.

The way I'm doing it, I iterate through each note in the track (i.e. each note I stored when I first read the MIDI), and go until the time matches the current counter time. Display that note. Then the timer ticks, counter increases, and repeat. But now we're repeating from the beginning of the track when counting, so while arriving at Note 1 in the track would be fast, I can assume the amount of iterations to get to Note 2000 is immense and probably redundant.
This is the code snippet i'm talking about:

```
foreach (var note in track)
{
if (note.NoteStart + note.NoteLength < PlaybackSeconds || note.Played) continue;
if (note.NoteStart > PlaybackSeconds) break;
//do my stuff here with this note
note.Played = true;
}
```

Even with my limited knowledge of the inner workings of things, I can see that this is not the optimal way to manage this process. Is there a more efficient way to store and then access this information that would cut down on processing time?

My development machine is an Intel Core i7, 16GB of DDR3 RAM and a SSD - so things run very quickly on my end, albeit with a fraction of a second delay no matter what I've tried (even setting the timer to 50ms). But a friend testing the program on his end is getting as much as 4 second delay, which is absolutely unacceptable.

Any suggestions on how to improve this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches I can see to optimize this:

1) Keep track of the index of the note that was last played (Looking at your code, I am assuming that you have the notes sorted by ascending order of NoteStart already because otherwise your break could lose some notes that might be in the playable window). The code would look something like this.

```
int lastPlayedIndex = 0;
for (int i = lastPlayedIndex; i < track.Length; i++)
{   
    // logic that you have already used to skip through nodes
    lastPlayedIndex = i;
}
```

You must make sure that lastPlayedIndex is actually stored in a place where it is accessible from multiple calls to this loop (maybe a class member)

2) Depending on the granularity of the PlaybackSeconds, you could make hashtable entries for each interval and store notes against those. For example, if the counter increases every 50 milliseconds, when you read the notes, you can create a hashtable that has entries (logically represented) like this

0 -> List of notes which start at/or after 0 but before 50

50 -> List of notes which start at/or after 50 but before 100
etc

When you read this, you can easily read the subset that needs to be played for a given PlaybackSeconds value.

Answer (score -1):

What is most likely taking the most time is what is happening in the `do my stuff here with this note` section. With what you are showing however, there are some things you can do:

First, create a new property on your `MIDINote` class for `NoteEnd`. Since you are iterating through your notes so much, having it be a property will save some time since you will not have to recalculate it every time (as in my next suggestion).

Second, you can create an `IEnumerable<>` object via linq that will replace your if logic:

```
var currentNotes = from n in tracks 
                   where !n.Played && (n.NoteStart < PlaybackSeconds 
                                       && n.NoteStart + n.NoteLength > PlaybackSeconds)
                   select n;
```

Your `foreach` loop then becomes:

```
foreach(var note in currentNotes)
{
    //do my stuff here with this note
    note.Played = true;
}
```

That probably wont do much for performance, but id does clean it up a bit. However, if you have written your code to be thread safe, you can utilize the `Parallel` library to gain some speed. If you have written your code such, you would then only need to change your `foreach` loop to be:

```
Parallel.ForEach(currentNotes, note =>
{
    //do my stuff here with this note with parallel processing
    note.Played = true;
});
```

Note, If your code is not thread safe, and you use the `Parallel` library, you will can (and will) get unexpected results that are extremely difficult to track down due to data races.

Comment: Parallelizing that brute-force algorithm will not help much on weak machines, which do not have many cores to begin with. And telling a beginner to just write thread-safe code is … unrealistic.

Comment: @CL I wouldn't say unrealistic, but uncommon. I've been coding for about the same amount of time and have built production ETL systems with the parallel library. And I did not tell him to write thread-safe code, I instead showed him a way to possibly speed up the method (especially on his machine) if his code can handle it. If it can't, he at least knows what another option is if he wants to improve it again later in time.